# Specify build and probe tables to hash join?

Tags: sql-server, join, hashing

I am observing a situation in AdventureWorks database where the hash join operator is building hash table using a larger input (296 rows) and then probing with a much smaller input (3 rows). I'm not able to understand why this reverse mapping is favoured by SQL server.

Following is the query and plan:

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER MERGE JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh ON e.BusinessEntityID = edh.BusinessEntityID
INNER HASH JOIN HumanResources.Shift s ON edh.ShiftID = s.ShiftID
```

The plan is here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk_YvD1iX

I wonder if I can specifically instruct SQL to use `HumanResources.Shift` for build and the other input to probe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hint a query like that, you force the join order -- you've actually answered your own question.

If you want to test join types and still leave the optimizer with room to explore things, use query options, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh 
ON e.BusinessEntityID = edh.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Shift s 
ON edh.ShiftID = s.ShiftID
OPTION(MERGE JOIN, HASH JOIN);
```

Comment: Adding `OPTION(MERGE JOIN, HASH JOIN) made the optimized use hash joins in both places, but I get your point. Wish there was the way to specify build and probe tables as well but that's the way SQL it is then :(

Comment: @upInCloud You can try getting creative with join syntax like this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/forcing-join-order-without-hints/